# Помогите понять кoд

Tags: c++

Заданы действительные числа ***x1, x 2,..., x16***. 
Получить *x1, x 3,...,x15, x2, x4,..., x16*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;




int main() {

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    
    int arr[16]{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    int temp;
    int s ;

    for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < 16; j += 2, i++) {
        temp = arr[j];
        for (s = j; s > i; s--) {
            arr[s] = arr[s - 1];
        }
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++
        ) {
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }


}
```

Comment: А что конкретно тебе не понятно? Ты сам код писал?

Comment: Велючите дебаггер, просмотрите в нем содержимое массива в начале и по оконяании каждой итерации -- должны увидеть как четные значения сдвигаются вправо, и в высвободившуюся ячейку записывается нечетное значение.

Comment: Попробуйте сами написать такую программу — после этого разобраться в чужом коде станет куда легче, а главное, вы будете *понимать*, что и как работает...

Comment: @Иван Павлов я не понимаю как четные числа идут в правую сторону, а нечетные в левую

Comment: @NowhereMan я пробовал, но так и не смог ничего разобрать

Comment: @Павел, штош ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @NowhereMan ))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каким образом происходит перемещение четных чисел в правую сторону, а нечетных в левую. В переменную `temp` записывается поитерационно (*каждый раз как проходит цикл for*) одно значение ***нечетного числа*** массива `arr`, далее меняется сам массив и сдвигается вправо на одну позицию, начиная с того места, где была взята переменная `temp`, потом та переменная, что была сохранена в `temp` записывается в начало массива 
`arr[i] = temp`(**нечетное число**). 
 А потом просто массив целиком выводится на экран. Если что непонятно спрашивай.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное))

Comment: Все понятно обьяснили

Comment: Отметь как верный, если все ок)

Comment: Извините, я новичок. Спасибо, что сказали